# How to call a graph showing various links between two columns?

Tags: word-request

I created a [kind of graph](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23defaultView%3ADimensions%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%0A%09%28SAMPLE%28%3Foperator_label%29%20as%20%3Foperator%29%20%28SAMPLE%28%3Fcountry_label%29%20as%20%3Fcountry%29%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%09%7B%20%3Fwikidata%20p%3AP31%2Fps%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2A%20wd%3AQ3917681.%20%7D%20UNION%20%7B%20%3Fwikidata%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ7843791.%20%7D%20%23%20Embassy%20or%20consulate%0A%09%3Fwikidata%20p%3AP31%2Fps%3AP31%20%3FtypeId.%20%3FtypeId%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Ftype_label.%20filter%20%28lang%28%3Ftype_label%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29.%0A%09OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fwikidata%20wdt%3AP131%2A%2Fwdt%3AP17%20%3FcountryId.%20%3FcountryId%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fcountry_label.%20filter%20%28lang%28%3Fcountry_label%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29.%7D%0A%09OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fwikidata%20wdt%3AP137%20%3FoperatorId.%20%3FoperatorId%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Foperator_label.%20filter%20%28lang%28%3Foperator_label%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29.%7D%0A%7D%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fwikidata) showing what countries have an embassy in what countries. It looks like this:

[image]

How to call such a graph?

Each item in the left column can be linked to zero, one or several items in the right column.

The left column and right column are the same, and no link can exist between the same item on left and right. If there is no English word for this, I can settle upon a word that describe a graph showing how Alice, Bob, Charles like apples, bananas, cherries.

Answer (score 2):

It is a form of

> Sankey graph or diagram

usually there is at least one link between the right and left sides, but it is possible to show a node without any links, and the size of the links are proportional to the value of the node.

[image: here]


[image: here]

Or, you may be thinking of a

> [bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph)

[image: here]

Comment: A Sankey diagram is all about quantities, if I am not mistaken? Wikipedia: "*Sankey diagrams are a specific type of flow diagram, in which the width of the arrows is shown proportionally to the flow quantity.*". So I have an extremely specific case of a Sankey diagram, where all quantities are 0 or 1.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, 0 and 1 are valid values / quantities. I've added an example of a bipartite graph.